# European Bulb E14 base 15w 110 volt dimmable bulb for Himalayan Salt Lamp

Tags: light-fixture, dimmer-switch, bulb, fire-hazard, voltage

The E14 base is European, as is the 110 voltage.  The bulb in question is a 15 watt bulb with dimmer control and is UL listed.

Is there any danger in using this rather than a bulb and dimmer specified for the US 120 volt?  Is the bulb in fact incandescent?

In addition, are there any known fire dangers?

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

[image: Kimisky Brand Lamp Bulb description enlarged from web page]

[Kimisky Himalayan Salt Lamp New Designs Giraffe Family Salt Lamp Night Light, UL-Certified New Dimmer Switch, 15W, Himalayan Himalayan Pink Salt Rock Lamps, 3 Bulbs SP-147 (Giraffe)](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B079D77GJS/ref=twister_B079D1F7JZ?_encoding=UTF8&th=1)

Comment: European voltage is generally 230V, _not_ 110V.

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely cheap Chinese.  The UL listing appears to be faked.

Feel free to buy the lamp for its aesthetic elements, but buy a boring old UL listed lamp for the actual light part.

Comment: Or use a low-voltage lighting setup for the actual light part ('tis what the salt lamps I've seen do -- they have a LED and dropper resistor spliced onto a USB cord, and plug into a bog-standard USB wallwart as a result)

Answer (score 1):

> The E14 base is European, as is the 110 voltage.

Yes and No.

E14 is typically European. But European voltage is typically 230. 110 is actually more of a US number. So right away that raises questions. In addition, it does not say the typical **UL Listed**. Instead it says **UL Certified**. Which is potentially OK, but another question to consider - as in: Is that any less tested/safe than UL Listed? Is it really UL Certified or is that just made up to sound good? etc.

I suspect the bulb is incandescent based on the size and wattage. The problem here is the same as the EZ Bake Oven: The bulb is expected to provide heat, and bulbs are rated based on their *light* output, not heat output. If you replace a 15W incandescent with a CFL or LED bulb that produces the same amount of light, the heat will be much lower and therefore the results will not be the same. On the other hand, if you replace it with a 15W CFL or LED, you will get similar heat but find that you have way too much light! Plus keep in mind that the dimmer may or may not work properly with CFL or LED bulbs depending on a number of factors.

The Amazon listing says the maximum is 25W, so assuming that:

- 110V is correct
- 25W maximum is correct
- The lamp is actually UL Certified

then yes, this should be fine in the US (110/115/120 are close enough together and in fact most devices designed for the US market should work properly anywhere from 110 - 120).

But those are quite a few assumptions. Caveat emptor.